# proper way of handling std::thread termination in child process after fork()

Tags: c++, multithreading, unix, c++11, multiprocessing

Frown as much as you want, I'm going to do it anyway :)

My question is: in the following code, what is the proper way to handle the termination of the `std::thread` in the subprocess generated by `fork()`? `std::thread::detach()` or `std::thread::join()`?

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

struct A { 

   void Fork()
   {   
      std::thread t(&A::Parallel, this);
      pid_t pid = fork();
      if(pid) {
         //parent
         t.join();
      } else {
         //child
         t.join(); // OR t.detach()?
      }   
   }   

   void Parallel()
   {   
      std::cout << "asd" << std::endl;
   }   
};

int main() {
   A a;
   a.Fork();
   return 0;
}
```

I know that only the thread that calls `fork()` is duplicated, which means that the `std::thread` is actually doing nothing in the child process right? Hence my doubt.

Comment: Don't do any of that. `fork` doesn't work in multithreaded programs.

Comment: @KerrekSB that is false. from `fork`'s manual:
The child process is created with a single thread—the one that  called fork(). The entire virtual address space of the parent is replicated in the child, including the states of  mutexes,  condition  variables, and  other pthreads objects; the use of pthread_atfork(3) may be helpful for dealing with problems that this can cause.

My application compiles and (as far as I can test) runs with no errors with both solutions, but I guess one must be preferred over the other.

Comment: @blue: I agree that it does "work" in that it runs. I disagree that it is a good idea or that it works for any program which does real work. The problem is that pretty much nothing is designed to handle it. Even things such as `malloc`: it uses a global lock in some cases, so guess what happens when a different thread was holding that lock when you forked.

Comment: I swear I read all the famous pages telling me this is a bad idea, and I know that in 99.9% of scenarios I'd be in for a lot of pain, but what I need to do in my 'real work' application is just spawning a thread that accepts connections, forking N times, and then waiting for the thread to join (which means the subprocesses have connected to the parent process). Everything is over in 10 lines of code, then I go back to plain multiprocessing. In good faith, I think this might work.

Comment: @blue: That's all fine and well until you hit your first deadlock in your multithreaded allocator. Yes, you can *call* `fork`, but it's subtle and non-obvious. Essentially you should consider yourself in an async-unsafe state after `fork`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `fork` [description](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fork.html), the proper way is to call `t.join()` only from parent process, as child one only replicates caller thread.

Note also, that child process in multithreaded program is allowed only to call functions available for signal handlers and `exec`.