# linux c++ use std::thread join, throw exception

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading

my project use three Level process mode. In order to the code after the fork does not inherit from the worker thread of the previous process, so create sub thread to fork sub process when each called.

**Now, I found some problems at following describe:**

**1.** the grandson process create a std::thread(work_thread), when called the join() method, it's  throw a exception
 **2.** if the son process dose not in sub thread call fork() method, then it's does not thow exception

**3.** if in grandson process create a empty std::thread(it's nothing to do) before the work thread create, and  the empty thread called join() method after the work thread called join() , then it is does not throw the exception. but if the empty thread called join() before work thread, it's also throw the same exception

if you can help me, please write your answer, i will thank you very much

the following code is test case:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <wait.h>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  std::thread t([]() {
    int l2pid = fork();
    if(l2pid > 0)
      waitpid(l2pid, NULL, 0);
    else if (l2pid == 0)
    {
      std::thread t2([]() {
        int l3pid = fork();
        if (l3pid > 0)
          waitpid(l3pid, NULL, 0);
        else if (l3pid == 0){
          //std::thread empty_thread([](){
          //});
          std::thread work_thread([](){
            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
              std::cout << "working..." << std::endl;
              std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
            }
          });
          if(work_thread.joinable())
            work_thread.join();
          //if(empty_thread.joinable())
           // empty_thread.join();
          std::cout << "L3 Process Exit!" << std::endl;
        }
      });
      if (t2.joinable())
        t2.join();
      std::cout << "L2 Process Exit!" << std::endl;
    }
  });
  if (t.joinable())
    t.join();
  std::cout << "Main Process Exit!" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

i use pthread_create and pthread_join also return EDEADLK

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <wait.h>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <pthread.h>
using namespace std;
void *work_thread(void *)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    std::cout << "working..." << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
  }
  return NULL;
}

void *t2_function(void *)
{
  int l3pid = fork();
  if (l3pid > 0)
  {
    waitpid(l3pid, NULL, 0);
  }
  else if (l3pid == 0)
  {
    pthread_t thread_handle;
    int ret = pthread_create(&thread_handle, NULL, work_thread, NULL);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
    void *pthread_ret = NULL;
    std::cout << "thread_handle:" << thread_handle << ",pthread_self:" << pthread_self() << std::endl;
    ret = pthread_join(thread_handle, &pthread_ret);
    std::cout << "pthread_join:" << ret << std::endl;
    std::cout << "L3 Process Exit!" << std::endl;
  }
}

void * t1_function(void *)
{
  int l2pid = fork();
  if (l2pid > 0)
    waitpid(l2pid, NULL, 0);
  else if (l2pid == 0)
  {
    pthread_t l2;
    pthread_create(&l2, NULL, t2_function, NULL);
    pthread_join(l2, NULL);
    std::cout << "L2 Process Exit!" << std::endl;
  }
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  pthread_t l1;
  pthread_create(&l1, NULL, t1_function, NULL);
  pthread_join(l1, NULL);
  std::cout << "L1 Process Exit!" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mixing forks and threads is asking for pain.
https://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/threads-and-fork-think-twice-before-using-them

Comment: Does this answer your question? [proper way of handling std::thread termination in child process after fork()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746439/proper-way-of-handling-stdthread-termination-in-child-process-after-fork)